# $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and connected $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ differentiable.$Df(x)=0$ $\forall x \in U$. then $f$ is constant.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, connectedness

Attempt:

Since U is open and connected, U is path connected. then there exists a path $\gamma(t):[0,1]\to U$ between any points $a,b\in U$ such that $\gamma(1)=b$ and $\gamma(0)=a$
Define $h(t)=(f\circ\gamma)(t):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^m$

What I want to do:

$h(1)-h(0)=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}f(\gamma(t))dt=\int_0^1Df(\gamma(t))\gamma^\prime(t)dt=0$

then $f(b)=f(a)$ $\forall a,b\in U$ so $f$ is constant. But I don't know that this path is differentiable, so this approach doesn't work.

Comment: What is to stop you from simply *choosing* a differentiable path?

Comment: The definition I have of path connected simply says there is a path for each a,b not that there is a differentiable one.

Comment: That is true.  I think though that you can show there is a differentiable path by starting with a continuous one, constructing an open cover, using compactness to find a *finite* open cover, an then in each element of *that* open cover explicitly presenting a differentiable path, and then making sure they "hook up" correctly.

Comment: @AColoredReptile $U$ is open, the path can be chosen to be differentiable.

Comment: @Jacky Chong Is there a name for this theorem or some proof of this result?

Comment: @AColoredReptile Locally everything reduces to open balls.

Comment: @Jacky Chong So I guess the idea is you connect straight lines between these balls where they intersect? But then how do you deal with them being "pointy" at these connections?

Comment: @AColoredReptile Then just smooth it out a little. Draw a picture.

Comment: I don't think you even need to smooth out the broken line. On each piece all OP's equalities hold, i.e., $h(t_i)-h(t_{i+1})=0$. Add them all together to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reduces to the case $m=1$. Let $a$ in $U$ and let $b=f(a)$. We will prove that $A=\{x\in U:f(x)=b\}$ is non-empty, open and closed in $U$. By definition, $a$ is in $A$ so $A$ is non-empty. Also $A=f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is closed because it is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function. Finally, if $p$ is in $A$, there exists a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that the open ball $B_\epsilon(p)$ of center $p$ and radius $\epsilon$ is included in $U$. Let $q$ in $B_\epsilon(p)\setminus\{p\}$. Consider the continuous function $g:t\in [0,1]\mapsto f(tq+(1-t)p)\in B_\epsilon(p)$. Then $g$ is differentiable in $(0,1)$ and its derivative is $g'(t)=D_{g(t)}f.(q-p)=0$. So $g$ is constant and in particular $g(0)=f(p)=f(q)=g(1)$. Then $q$ is in $A$ and thus $B_\epsilon(p)\subseteq A$. So $A$ is open. We conclude that $A=U$ because $U$ is connected.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why you can reduce this to m=1?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can prove the result for each coordinate $f_i$, with $1\leq i \leq m$, of $f$. Do you see it? Recall that the rows of the differential matrix of $f$ are the gradients of the coordinates $f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove the result by contradiction as follows:

If possible let $ f$ is not a constant.

Then the cardinality of $\text{Image (f) or Im(f)}$ must be greater than $1$.

Let $ v \in Im(f)$ and consider the following two sets:

$ A=f^{-1}\{v \}$ and $B=f^{-1} (Im(f) \setminus \{v \})$.

Now it is your task to show that (use continuity of $f$):

$(i) \ A,B $ are non-empty sets,

$(ii) \ A, B $ are both open sets,

$(iii) \ A \cup B=U$,

$(iv) \ A \cap B=\phi$.

By separation axiom $ U$ is disconnected because given that $U$ is connected.

Hence a contradiction.

This prove that $ f$ must be constant.